# Can't move or delete components in AutoDesk Eagle

Tags: autodesk-eagle

Currently using the free version (9.6.2) of [AutoDesk Eagle](https://www.autodesk.com/products/eagle/overview) for circuit board designing. It has been working great for me for months but all of a sudden I can no longer move, select, or delete components. I can change nodes and paths but not components themselves.  See below:

[image]

This is true regardless of any operation I try to do with any block. Also true on the BRD layout side of Eagle as well. Any suggestions would be helpful. Perhaps a setting or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I had some layers hidden. This is still good to know though! If you have even part of the component hidden through layers, Eagle will not let you move, delete, etc to the entire group.

The solution is to unhide all layers.